# Powershell script - Azure sql db - json file

Tags: json, azure

I'm creating a pwsh script for json population.

```
   $SqlServers="kc-emea-sqsrv-00","kc-emea-sqsrv-01","kc-emea-sqsrv-02","kc-emea-sqsrv-03"
   $SqlServerResourceGroup="KC-EMEA-RSGP-00","KC-EMEA-RSGP-01","KC-EMEA-RSGP-02","KC-EMEA-RSGP-03"
```

I'd like to access in sequence to each value in the above array.

```
    foreach ($SqlServer in $SqlServers) {
    az sql db list --resource-group $SqlServerResourceGroup --server $SqlServer --query "[].{name:name,value:name}" -o json *>  "C:\script\json\$SqlServers.json"
    }
```

How can I access in sequence at $SqlServerResourceGroup array variables in order to create a json for each server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a for loop to achieve that:

```
For ($i=0; $i -lt $SqlServers.Length; $i++) {
   az sql db list --resource-group $SqlServerResourceGroup[$i] --server $SqlServers[$i] --query "[].{name:name,value:name}" -o json *>  "C:\script\json\$SqlServers.json"
}
```

Comment: It worked. Is it possible also to have the Value in the final path of the query?  -o json *> "c:\script\json\$SqlServers[$i].json" ? How can I escape square bracket in powershell?

Comment: Try "c:\script\json\$($SqlServers[$i]).json".